# CHAD (world 2 boss) level bugged in Super Meat Boy on OSX

Tags: technical-issues, macos, super-meat-boy

I get the key at the beginning of the level, but the stage doesn't start: the locks open but the screen stays fixed. The boss jumps up and down, always in the center of the screen.

Is this a known bug, somehow work-aroundable? I guess I could copy the savegame to a windows box and play there this level, hoping it works?

Comment: Perhaps this issue would be better for the [offical super meat boy forums](http://supermeatboy.com/forum/index.php).  Post back here if you find a solution, or hear from the devs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a [known](http://supermeatboy.com/forum/index.php/topic,2181.0.html), and so far ignored, problem.

One kind-of workaround is to set the graphics to -ultralowdetail, which for some weird reason usually solves this (revert to normal details later, because the ultralow are really ultralow and horrible as it sounds).

Sometimes, even with higher details, if you go at one end of the screen and then another end, and do a little jump, the level starts scrolling. It's not much good, since it increases way too much startup time and frustration.